# Reset PHP Error before running included script

Tags: php, wordpress

I am combining two existing scripts to built something new and safe time by using existing code:

1. php_simple_html_dom to parse some html
2. the wp-db.php class from wordpress to access the database

These two scripts don't play nicely along. I used xdebug to find out that the main problem was caused in this piece of code in php_simple_html_dom:

```
    if (($error=error_get_last())>null) {
        $this->clear();
        return false;
    }
```

Because the wordpress template I use fires some E_NOTICE level errors this results in my php_simple_html_dom getting cleared.

<s>The weird thing is, I do not include any template code as I include and instantiate wp-db.php myself like this:</s>

```
require_once('../wp-config.php');
require_once('../wp-includes/wp-db.php');

$wpdb = new wpdb(DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME,DB_HOST);
```

Even when I step through the code completely with xdebug it never hits anything else from wordpress then wp-config.php or wp-db.php.

Edit:

> As indicated by horatio, this actually does get called from the
>   include of wp-settings.php in the end of wp-config.php. I now
>   understand why my debugger never hit it: netbeans had failed to
>   download wp-settings.php so it could not debug it.

Nevertheless this is the error returned by `error_get_last()`:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 8
    [message] => Undefined index:  id
    [file] => (real-path-deleted)/wp-content/themes/supermassive/lib/inc/options.php
    [line] => 10
)
```

I think I could solve this problem using one of two different strategies:

<s>1. Stop the unneccessary wordpress code that is causing the errors from running.</s>

1. Reset the error returned by `error_get_last()` before php_simple_html_dom is run.

Which of these would be the best and how would I go about to achieve it?

Comment: according to the wp online source repository, wp-config.php has a require in it which then requires a whole bucket full of other includes.

Comment: That would indicate strategy 1 is not really feasible

Comment: I sort of solved it by changing the code in php_simple_html_dom to:
`if ($error>null && $error['type']!=8)`